# R: quotes in character factors

Tags: r

How should quotes in one level of a character factor be entered so that the resulting numeric contains values of 1, 2, or 3 (for 'Neither "a" or "b") ?  The two tries below did not give me the desired result.  Thanks.

```
> table(MM2$a.9)

             FALSE Neither “a” or “b”               TRUE 
                34                 90                583 
> MM2$a04f <- as.numeric(factor(MM2$a.9, levels=c ('TRUE','FALSE','Neither “a” or “b”')))
> table(MM2$a04f)

  1   2 
583  34 
> MM2$a04f <- as.numeric(factor(MM2$a.9, levels=c ("TRUE","FALSE","Neither \"a\" or \"b\"")))
> table(MM2$a04f)

  1   2 
583  34
```

Comment: Could you post some mock data?

Comment: Can you try renaming that column to something simpler?

Answer (score 0):

*(I'm posting this as an "answer" even though it's really a comment ... just so I can have more control over the code I'm posting.)*

I created some fake data and your second approach worked on it.

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "Neither \"a\" nor \"b\"", 
    "TRUE", "FALSE", "Neither \"a\" nor \"b\"", "TRUE", "FALSE", 
    "Neither \"a\" nor \"b\"")), .Names = "x", class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -9L))
df
df$x
table(df$x)
table(as.numeric(factor(df$x, levels=c("TRUE", "FALSE", "Neither \"a\" nor \"b\""))))
```

I suggest that you use dput() to share a small portion of your data frame or list so we have something to test methods out on.  For example, if there is record with 'Neither "a\" nor "b"' in the first six lines of your data frame, this would work.

```
dput(head(MM2))
```